# Xcode warning: The specified input encoding is Unicode (UTF-8), but file contents appear to be Unicode (UTF-16); treating as Unicode (UTF-16)

Tags: xcode, localization, warnings, localizable.strings

I create the .strings file by using `genstrings` command. Output file of this command encoded with UTF-16, but when i add generated .strings file to my project and then bild, Xcode show warning:

> The specified input encoding is Unicode (UTF-8), but file contents
>   appear to be Unicode (UTF-16); treating as Unicode (UTF-16).

I open .strings file in textEdit.app and resave it with UTF-16, but this haven't effect.

Hot to fix this? 
Thaks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I could not reproduce the problem, but the easiest solution is probably to select the strings file in Xcode and set the "Text Encoding" to "UTF-16" in the File inspector.

[image]

Comment: I don't found "Text Encoding" in File inspector.

Comment: @NikolaiNagorny: Select the file in Xcode and choose "View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector" from the menu. I have added a screenshot to the answer.

Comment: Ok! When you add more than one localization to the project, the .strings files embeded to group. To see "Text Encoding" in File inspector necessary select separate file in the group. Thaks!!!

Comment: There is no Text Encoding options in XCode 10

Comment: @ArtFeel: Yes, there is, in the File Inspector.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but not for Localizable Strings Dictionary. You should change file Type to something with textual representation first.